# I want to use special characters for naming my module in Pypi

Tags: python, module, pypi

What characters can I use in naming my Python library and what characters can't I use?

For example _ or - or . or & or = etc

Comment: Which names, specifically, are you asking about? Package names, module names, distribution packages names, something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) tells what are valid names for identifiers in Python. The short version:

> *the uppercase and lowercase letters `A` through `Z`, the underscore `_` and, except for the first character, the digits `0` through 9`*

This is also valid for the names of your importable packages (this things you actually `import` in your code).

For the names of distribution packages (the things that you *pip*-install), the rules are a bit different, dashes `-` and dots `.` are allowed. But because of conventions and normalization rules that are a bit complex to explain here (especially without knowing what your intentions are), I strongly recommend avoiding dashes, underscores, and dots. Only use letters `a` to `z`, and I would also recommend only using the lower cases.